# Excel converting numerical strings(eg: "123") to numbers when exporting csv in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am currently using excel_csv(http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/excel_csv/0.0.2) to export active record objects to csv files for users to edit and then import them later on. When I export data to csv, excel seems to be converting numerical strings(eg: "123" or "123-231") to actual numbers.

I am currently prepending these strings with a ' and stripping these off when importing the spreadsheets, but is there a cleaner way to fix this? (eg: save the value as directly as a string  in excel without modifying it at the time of export)

Below is some example code to explain what I am currently trying to do for the export:

```
rows = [["1", "col x", "col y"],
        ["2", "col x", "col y"],
        ["3", "col x", "col y"],]


 stringio = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zio|
  zio.put_next_entry("export.csv")

  str = ExcelCSV.generate(force_quotes: true) do |csv|
    rows.each do |row|
      csv << row 
    end
  end

  zio.write str
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far. It's not clear what you're doing here. Are you trying to export data from Rails into a CSV file and then import it into Excel, or are you trying to export data from Excel and import it into Rails?

Comment: The problem is that data in a CSV file has no type. Everything is just a sequence of characters. As far as I know there's no way to give Excel a "hint" about the type of a value. One possible solution would be to use a gem for writing Excel files (`.xlsx`) rather than CSV files. Your other option is to handle this when you're doing the importing on Excel.